# how to solve programming chess piece logical problem?

Tags: c#

I'm currently building a chess game using 64 buttons acting as the board and as can be seen below I have put them into a list (listed from left to right and bottom to top. e.g, bottom left corner is Block1, Bottom right is Block8, top left is block57, top right is block64), when clicking on a chess piece the blocks where the piece is able to move to is subscribed to the on click event "destination_clicked" so that when the one button out of all potential valid moves is clicked it will move the piece there.

The main problem is that I have relied upon adding a certain number to the index of the list containing buttons to determine the possible valid moves of a piece (e.g adding 8 to index of list of buttons to move pawn up one square as buttons one square up will always be 8 more counting from left to right and bottom to top).

However for every other piece which can move diagonally such as the Knight and Bishop, they cannot be confined like this as if they are near the edge of the board the movements will not be valid (e.g Knight is normally able to use index + 6 to move up one and left two blocks but if on block 17, it just moves right six to block 23 and using index - 10 to normally move one down and two left would instead move two down and seven to the right to block 7).

Note: if possible I would not like to change my base code too much or use any overly complex methods but still feel free to make any suggestions.

```
public void Setpieces()
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Count; i++)
            {
                buttons[i].Tag = ChessPiece.None;
            }

            Block16.Tag = ChessPiece.WPawn;
            Block15.Tag = ChessPiece.WPawn;
            Block14.Tag = ChessPiece.WPawn;
            Block13.Tag = ChessPiece.WPawn;
            Block12.Tag = ChessPiece.WPawn;
            Block11.Tag = ChessPiece.WPawn;
            Block10.Tag = ChessPiece.WPawn;
            Block9.Tag = ChessPiece.WPawn;

            Block1.Tag = ChessPiece.WRook;
            Block2.Tag = ChessPiece.WKnight;
            Block3.Tag = ChessPiece.WBishop;
            Block4.Tag = ChessPiece.WQueen;
            Block5.Tag = ChessPiece.WKing;
            Block6.Tag = ChessPiece.WBishop;
            Block7.Tag = ChessPiece.WKnight;
            Block8.Tag = ChessPiece.WRook;

            Block49.Tag = ChessPiece.BPawn;
            Block50.Tag = ChessPiece.BPawn;
            Block51.Tag = ChessPiece.BPawn;
            Block52.Tag = ChessPiece.BPawn;
            Block53.Tag = ChessPiece.BPawn;
            Block54.Tag = ChessPiece.BPawn;
            Block55.Tag = ChessPiece.BPawn;
            Block56.Tag = ChessPiece.BPawn;

            Block57.Tag = ChessPiece.BRook;
            Block58.Tag = ChessPiece.BKnight;
            Block59.Tag = ChessPiece.BBishop;
            Block60.Tag = ChessPiece.BQueen;
            Block61.Tag = ChessPiece.BKing;
            Block62.Tag = ChessPiece.BBishop;
            Block63.Tag = ChessPiece.BKnight;
            Block64.Tag = ChessPiece.BRook;

        }

        static List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
        public void ListofBlocks()
        {
            Button[] Blocks =
            {
                    Block1, Block2, Block3, Block4, Block5, Block6, Block7, Block8, Block9, Block10,
                    Block11, Block12, Block13, Block14, Block15, Block16, Block17, Block18, Block19, Block20,
                    Block21, Block22, Block23, Block24, Block25, Block26, Block27, Block28, Block29, Block30,
                    Block31, Block32, Block33, Block34, Block35, Block36, Block37, Block38, Block39, Block40,
                    Block41, Block42, Block43, Block44, Block45, Block46, Block47, Block48, Block49, Block50,
                    Block51, Block52, Block53, Block54, Block55, Block56, Block57, Block58, Block59, Block60,
                    Block61, Block62, Block63, Block64
            };

            buttons.AddRange(Blocks);
        }


        private void ChessBlock_clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Count; i++)
            {
                buttons[i].Click -= destination_clicked;
            }

            if (sender is Button btn)
            {

                ChessPiece piece = (ChessPiece)btn.Tag;
                Global.SelectedPiece = piece.ToString();

                int index;
                Button destination = null;

                index = buttons.IndexOf(btn);
                Global.SelectedBtn = buttons[(index) % buttons.Count];

                switch (piece)
                {
                    case ChessPiece.WPawn:
                        textBox3.Text = "W pawn";

                        destination = buttons[(index + 8) % buttons.Count];
                        destination.Click += destination_clicked;

                        break;

                    case ChessPiece.WRook:
                        textBox3.Text = "W Rook";
                        break;

                    case ChessPiece.WBishop:
                        textBox3.Text = "W Bishop";
                        break;

                    case ChessPiece.WQueen:
                        textBox3.Text = "W Queen";
                        break;

                    case ChessPiece.WKnight:
                        textBox3.Text = "W Knight";

                        destination = buttons[(index - 17) % buttons.Count];
                        destination.Click += destination_clicked;
                        destination = buttons[(index - 15) % buttons.Count];
                        destination.Click += destination_clicked;
                        destination = buttons[(index - 10) % buttons.Count];
                        destination.Click += destination_clicked;
                        destination = buttons[(index - 6) % buttons.Count];
                        destination.Click += destination_clicked;
                        destination = buttons[(index + 6) % buttons.Count];
                        destination.Click += destination_clicked;
                        destination = buttons[(index + 10) % buttons.Count];
                        destination.Click += destination_clicked;
                        destination = buttons[(index + 15) % buttons.Count];
                        destination.Click += destination_clicked;
                        destination = buttons[(index + 17) % buttons.Count];
                        destination.Click += destination_clicked;

                        break;

                    case ChessPiece.WKing:
                        textBox3.Text = "W King";

                        break;

                    case ChessPiece.BPawn:
                        textBox3.Text = "B Pawn";

                        destination = buttons[(index - 8) % buttons.Count];
                        destination.Click += destination_clicked;

                        break;

                    case ChessPiece.BRook:
                        textBox3.Text = "B Rook";
                        break;

                    case ChessPiece.BBishop:
                        textBox3.Text = "B Bishop";
                        break;

                    case ChessPiece.BQueen:
                        textBox3.Text = "B Queen";
                        break;

                    case ChessPiece.BKnight:
                        textBox3.Text = "B Knight";
                        break;

                    case ChessPiece.BKing:
                        textBox3.Text = "B King";
                        break;
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what the problem is. Is your code not working as you intend it to? If so please elaborate how you code is behaving incorrectly.

Comment: I would add, however, that since chess is a 2D game, why not arrange the fields/buttons/blocks in a 2D array instead of a long 1D array?

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask. Your question is very broad and it is unclear what you are asking or what the exact specific problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider referring to the position of a button according to two numbers (column,row).

You can write a function that converts row,column to an index easily enough `(row * 8 + column)`.

That way you can check that a particular row / column exists or not.  e.g., a knight that moves from 0,0 can move to (1,2), or (2,1) but not to (2,-1) or any other pair with a negative number.  Similarly, (7,7) cannot move to (8,6) because column "8" doesn't exist.